# Impossible to launch nop.Admin web project with vs 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I downloaded nopcommerce v2.65 and i met 2 problems , and i managed to resolve the first.
First problem :
Unable debugging the project , and the solution is to modify ProjectExtensions section of Nop.Admin.csproj like this :

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>2619</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:2451/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Second problem , that i don't find the solution :

When i launch the Nop.Admin web site , i get the follwing error :

La ressource est introuvable.
Description : HTTP 404. La ressource recherchée (ou l'une de ses dépendances) a peut-être été supprimée ou renommée ou bien elle n'est plus disponible temporairement. Vérifiez l'URL ci-après et assurez-vous qu'elle est correcte.

URL demandée: /

That's normal because we must define routes registerinng in global  the global.asax file , so i create Gloab.asax file, and i wrote :

```
 public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                      // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",   // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
        }
    }
```

-> Now i have a new error in  execution : impossible to load global asax :(

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

The Nop.Admin project can't be launched by itself. In Visual Studio Solution Explorer, you need to set Nop.Web as the start up project (right-click the project name and select 'Set as StartUp Project'; you can then launch the site with F5 or Ctl+F5.

You can access the admin area by logging in as an administrator (an admin is created during install with the credentials you provide) and clicking the Administration link in the header.